# Determine if all values in a vector are unique

Tags: c++

What is wrong with this code?

```
class Solution {
public:
  bool uniqueOccurrences(vector<int> &arr) {
    map<int, int> mp;
    for (auto x : arr) {
      mp[x]++;
    }
    vector<int> v;
    for (auto x : mp) {
      v.push_back(x.second);
    }
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; i++) {
      if (v[i] != v[i + 1])
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
};
```

Given an array of integers arr, return true if the number of occurrences of each value in the array is unique or false otherwise.

This was the question statement and was working fine with various test cases but fails in the follow test case: [3,5,-2,-3,-6,-6] should return false but returns true

Comment: Please describe what the code should do in words (other than the specific test case result).

Comment: Given an array of integers arr, return true if the number of occurrences of each value in the array is unique or false otherwise.

 this was the question statement

Comment: The quick fix is to change the expression `v[i] != v[i + 1]` to use `==` and swap your returns. The early return condition is if two values are the same, not if they're different. The better solution is to push the counts into a `std::unordered_set`. It's a container that can only contain unique values. Once all values have been inserted, return the result of the equivalency between the sizes of your unordered_map and unordered_set.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (v[i] != v[i + 1])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
```

You should swap the `return true` and `return false`.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (v[i] != v[i + 1])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
```

Comment: Either case returns too early. Since the check is for non-equivalency, don't they have to ensure they look at all elements? If the check were instead for equivalency, then swapping the returns makes sense, and returning false on finding two identical values should be the condition for an early return.

Comment: I found the question on leetcode and tested out my suggestion and it passes. Although, the algorithm can be sped up a bit by using an unordered_set instead of a vector that requires sorting. If the size of the unordered_set is the same size as the map, return true, false otherwise.